# systemctl Persistent timer and service, when computer turned off

Tags: software-updates, systemctl, systemd-timer, persistence, unattended-upgrades

How do the **systemctl** **timer** works when the computer is turned off at the given trigger time?
There is the option "`Persistent`", but when exactly is the command executed?
In how far is it guaranteed that the command will be safely executed, e.g. that a maximum of given time shall not pass between two executions?

status:

```
$ systemctl status mintupdate-automation-upgrade.timer
● mintupdate-automation-upgrade.timer - Update Manager automatic upgrades
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mintupdate-automation-upgrade.timer; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Fri 2021-01-22 20:20:24 CET; 4 days ago
    Trigger: Thu 2021-01-28 00:44:21 CET; 12h left
   Triggers: ● mintupdate-automation-upgrade.service
```

configuration files

```
$ systemctl cat mintupdate-automation-upgrade.*
# /lib/systemd/system/mintupdate-automation-upgrade.timer
[Unit]
Description=Update Manager automatic upgrades

[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
OnStartupSec=60m
RandomizedDelaySec=60m
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

# /lib/systemd/system/mintupdate-automation-upgrade.service
[Unit]
Description=Update Manager automatic upgrades
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
CPUQuota=50%
CPUWeight=20
IOWeight=20
ExecStart=/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/automatic_upgrades.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The timer has the Persistent flag, but the service (is triggered by timer) has not

```
$ systemctl show mintupdate-automation-upgrade.timer --property=Persistent
Persistent=yes
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems **not to work**, when the computer is turned off or no internet connection, it will not catch up as the message still says:

```
$ systemctl --no-pager status mintupdate-automation-upgrade.timer
...
Trigger: Tue 2021-02-02 00:32:40 CET; 13h left
```

So the update process (at least using this method, maybe in contrast to `unattended-upgrades`) is **not really safe**.

If there is the possibility to fix it, let me know?

Comment: This seems to be a comment to your question rather than a solution. Perhaps you want to edit it into the question text as "approaches tried".

Comment: Unfortunately it is an answer (actually /the/ answer), stating that the timer will not trigger in the case described in my entry post, which basically means that it might occur that the timer never triggers if the computer is turned off over night, which in turn is a pity, in this case related to the security concern

Answer (score 1):

`Persistent=` is only applicable to timers (see [`man systemd.timer`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#Persistent=)). That's why you don't see it with

```
systemctl show mintupdate-automation-upgrade.service --property=Persistent
```

When we look at the timer it says:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=daily
OnStartupSec=60m
RandomizedDelaySec=60m
Persistent=true
```

- [`OnCalendar=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#OnCalendar=)[`daily`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#Calendar%20Events): Defines realtime (i.e. wallclock) timers with calendar event expression [`daily`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.time.html#Calendar%20Events).  which effectively means that it will run at midnight every night.
- [`Persistent=true`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#Persistent=): means "The time when the service unit was last triggered is stored on disk. When the timer is activated, the service unit is triggered immediately if it would have been triggered at least once during the time when the timer was inactive. Such triggering is nonetheless subject to the delay imposed by RandomizedDelaySec=. This is useful to catch up on missed runs of the service when the system was powered down."
- [`OnStartupSec=60m`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#Options) defines a timer relative to when the service manager was first started.
- [`RandomizedDelaySec=60m`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html#RandomizedDelaySec=) Delays the timer by a randomly selected, evenly distributed amount of time between 0 and 60m. Each timer unit will determine this delay randomly before each iteration, and the delay will simply be added on top of the next determined elapsing time.  This setting is useful to stretch dispatching of similarly configured timer events over a certain time interval, to prevent them from firing all at the same time, possibly resulting in resource congestion.

So if you leave your machine on overnight, it'll fire between midnight and 01h00.  If you reboot your machine it'll fire between 1 and 2 hours after boot.   If you shutdown your machine overnight, then in the morning it'll trigger within 1 hour of booting (for the `OnCalendar`/`Persistent` trigger) then again between 1 and 2 hours of booting (for the `OnStartupSec` trigger).

I suspect you're most worried about the case when you boot your machine at 23h00.  In that case, it'll fire twice between 00h00 and 01h00. When a trigger fires, it will be ignored if the `oneshot` service is still in the `activating` state which is the case while the `ExecStart=` is still running.  Therefore you will not have two concurrent triggers of the same service and hence it is safe.

But then you ask about a minimum time between two executions.  We generally try not to keep things safe with "time".  This is akin to adding `sleep` in a bash script which is usually a work-around when we are too lazy to listen for the appropriate signals (`./foo & sleep 5 && ./bar`).   It's also volatile-work around as there is no guarantee that things will actually be ready when the time expires.  If this script is written well, it should execute several times in a row without needing any time separating it (`./foo && ./foo && ./foo`), and so you shouldn't have to worry about the safety.

Comment: "If you reboot your machine it'll fire between 1 and 2 hours after boot"
Sorry, that contradicts my experience, as I have rebooted my machine right now (local time was about 3pm) and it said "Trigger: Wed 2021-03-17 00:33:22 CET; 5h 43min left" which will again not trigger since the computer will be shutdown then

Comment: That's how it's documented at least.  Still your main question is about how to keep the service "safe" from consecutive runs.  I don't think consecutive runs are a problem for reasons mentioned above.